# Rest API internal Server Error Due to Null Pointer Exception Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I created a Springboot REST API application with a regular structure of

- Controller,
- Service used by a controller
- An Interface defining functions
- Another service defining what functions are referred in Interface
- entity

While trying to fetch the Post request from PostMan getting a Null Exception error at the `readRecosFromCsv` function at the point where I am trying to add the new Entity to a List
at this point exactly

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            System.out.println("Point 4");
            String line_l;
            while ((line_l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String value_1=line_l.substring(0,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 1));
                String value_2=line_l.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 1)+1,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 2));
                String value_3=line_l.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 2)+1,line_l.length());
                System.out.println(value_1+"::"+value_2+"::"+value_3);
// ------Point where the error is occuring ------
                known_recos.add(new RPL_Recos(value_1, value_2,value_3));
                }
        }catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It makes no sense as to why would a null pointer come up at the add to the list part even though entity creation showed up no error

I created 2 services because I intent to add this code to an existing codebase without much of any issues

Code and Error attached below , any response or hint where its wrong would be appreciated

Controller

```
@RestController
public class Test_Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Test_Service testService;
    
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/find_by_name_story")
    public Map<String, Object> getByNameAndStory(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Point 1 Request Recieved");
        testService.getDirectReadFunction();
        return response;
    }
}
```

1st Service

```
@Service
public class Test_Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private RPL_Recos_Service reco_known_service;
    
    public Map<String, Object> getDirectReadFunction() {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Point 2");
        reco_known_service.readRecosFromCsv("/home/blesson/eclipse-workspace_2/SampleDataGenerator/RPL_Table.csv");
        List<RPL_Recos> reco_output = reco_known_service.findRecosFromCustAndStory("customer_1@email.com", "UC001.Hybridizer.Reorder");
        System.out.println(reco_output.get(0).getRecos());  
        return response;
    }
```

2nd Service

```
@Service
public class RPL_Reco_OutService implements RPL_Recos_Service{
    
    private List<RPL_Recos> known_recos;
    @Override
    public void readRecosFromCsv(String filename){
        // Insert into file 
        System.out.println("Point 3");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            System.out.println("Point 4");
            String line_l;
            while ((line_l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String value_1=line_l.substring(0,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 1));
                String value_2=line_l.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 1)+1,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 2));
                String value_3=line_l.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line_l, "|", 2)+1,line_l.length());
                System.out.println(value_1+"::"+value_2+"::"+value_3);
                known_recos.add(new RPL_Recos(value_1, value_2,value_3));
                }
        }catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public List<RPL_Recos> findRecosFromCustAndStory(String cust_id,String story_id) {
        return known_recos.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getCustId().equals(cust_id) && p.getStoryId().equals(story_id))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Interface

```
@Component
public interface RPL_Recos_Service {
    void readRecosFromCsv(String filename);
    List<RPL_Recos> findRecosFromCustAndStory(String cust_id,String story_id);
}
```

Entity

```
public class RPL_Recos {
    private String cust_id;
    private String story_id;
    private String recos;
    
    public RPL_Recos(String cust_id,String story_id,String recos) {
        this.cust_id=cust_id;
        this.story_id=story_id;
        this.recos=recos;
    }
    
    public String getCustId() {
        return cust_id;
    }
    
    public String getStoryId() {
        return story_id;
    }
    
    public String getRecos() {
        return recos;
    }
    
    public void setCustId(String cust_id) {
         this.cust_id=cust_id;
    }
    
    public void setStoryId(String story_id) {
        this.story_id=story_id;
    }
    
    public void setRecos(String recos) {
        this.recos=recos;
    }

}
```

Error

```
ization in 1 ms
Point 1 Request Recieved
Point 2
Point 3
Point 4
Customer_Id::Story_Id::Recos
2023-03-08 09:00:36.120 ERROR 16791 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.ArrayStructureTest.service.RPL_Reco_OutService.readRecosFromCsv(RPL_Reco_OutService.java:35) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.ArrayStructureTest.service.Test_Service.getDirectReadFunction(Test_Service.java:32) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.ArrayStructureTest.controller.Test_Controller.getByNameAndStory(Test_Controller.java:33) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
```

Comment: 2nd Service - "private List<RPL_Recos> known_recos;", member variables are initialized to their default value. So in this case, since it is an object it is init to Null. That's why when you try to add records, it gives NPE. I don't know why Service would need a state, seems like this definition needs to go inside the `readRecosFromCsv` method otherwise per request you have the same shared state being updated. But you still need to do `List<RPL_Recos> known_recos = new ArrayList<>`.

Comment: One of the value_s may failed to be properly collected or tainted, recos appears to be gained from a call to an instance whereas value_1 and Value_2 are related to some type of query. You may not placed any data in the db to extract if null is allowed an the column.

Comment: Thanks ,this was helpful, can see the response properly now